# PanTo() for google maps api without jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not a developer, stuck in this `panTo()`. All I want is to run this function with if-else statement without loading new google map and without jQuery.

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="abc" onclick="main(1)">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="def" onclick="main(2)">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="ghi" onclick="main(3)">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="jkl" onclick="main(4)">D</a></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</div>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFX2v5z34vYKl0We4nHV4KFV1j6uVsltg&callback=main"></script>
```

and function is:

```
function main(number) {
var map;
var map= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(33.72939,73.09315),
    zoom:10,
    };

if (number==1) {
    map.setCenter(51.508742,-0.120850);
}else if (number==2) {
    map.setCenter(33.72939,73.09315);
}else if (number==3) {
    map.setCenter(33.939445,73.34587);
}else{
    alert("Sorry! No Place found with name ")
}
var map1= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),map);
}
```

Comment: `href="#"` will scroll your website to top. You don't want that. (Hopefully someone will show you how to prevent that while posting an answer)

Comment: You might want to edit out your API key and revoke it if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `map.setCenter( latLngObject );` not `map.setCenter( "lat", "lng" );`

```js
// don't complicate using else/if-s. Simplify your code!

var locations = { // name : [lat, lng]
  "1" : [51.508742, -0.120850],
  "2" : [33.72939, 73.09315],
  "3" : [33.939445, 73.34587]
};

// Define map Object
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  // common map options here
  zoom: 16,
});


function main( name ){
  
  if(!(name in locations)) return alert("Sorry! No Place found with name: "+ name);
  // Create a new LatLng Object
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( locations[name][0], locations[name][1] );
  map.setCenter( latLng );
}


// Init map using location name "2"
main("2");
```

```css
#map{height:200px;}
li {display: inline-block;} li a{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="abc" onclick="main(1)">A</a></li>
  <li><a id="def" onclick="main(2)">B</a></li>
  <li><a id="ghi" onclick="main(3)">C</a></li>
  <li><a id="jkl" onclick="main(4)">D</a></li>
</ul>
  
<div id="map"></div>  
  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFX2v5z34vYKl0We4nHV4KFV1j6uVsltg"></script>
```

notice also that I removed the `&callback` after the google maps URI